# How can I aggregate interfaces into with castle dynamic proxy

Tags: castle-dynamicproxy, mixins

I would like to allow for declarative mixin management in my codebase.  I would like to declare an interface like

```
public interface IMyRepo : IRepository, ICanFindPeopleByName, ICantSing {}
```

So my classes can consume only the bits of the data access layer they need.  In my IoC container I would like to aggregate the implementations of these interfaces into a single instance.  However when I do things similar to the referenced threads, the generator throws an exception stating that interfaces are implemented in multiple places.  What can I do, other than implementing my own interceptor and passing through?

Relevant Threads:

- [Help Migrating mixins from Castle.DynamicProxy to DynamicProxy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656663/help-migrating-mixins-from-castle-dynamicproxy-to-dynamicproxy2/2657506#2657506).
- [Windsor MixIn is a Singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678131/windsor-mixin-is-a-singleton)

---

Better Example (wall of code)

```
public interface IIceCream {
    void Eat();
}
public class IceCream : IIceCream {
    public void Eat() { Console.WriteLine("Yummy!"); }
}
public interface ICake {
    void NomNom();
}
public class Cake : ICake {
    public void NomNom() { Console.WriteLine("Cakey!"); }
}
public interface ISprinkles {
    void Oogle();
}
public class Sprinkles : ISprinkles {
    public void Oogle(){ Console.WriteLine("Its Pretty!");}
}

public interface IIceCreamWithCakeAndSprinkles : IIceCream, ICake, ISprinkles {}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var gen = new ProxyGenerator();
        var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions();

        options.AddMixinInstance(new IceCream());
        options.AddMixinInstance(new Cake());
        options.AddMixinInstance(new Sprinkles());

        var result =
            gen.CreateClassProxy(typeof (object), new[] {typeof (IIceCreamWithCakeAndSprinkles)}, options) as IIceCreamWithCakeAndSprinkles;

    }
}
```

throws

```
InvalidMixinConfigurationException: "The mixin IceCream adds the interface 'ConsoleApplication1.IIceCream' to the generated proxy, but the interface already exists in the proxy's additional interfaces. A mixin cannot add an interface already implemented in another way."
```

Comment: What exception exactly are you getting DP won't let you create proxy when there's ambiguity, that is when you're trying to add as mixins multiple types that implement any particular interface, since then it won't know which implementation to forward to.

Comment: In this case, none of the mixin objects specified implement the same interfaces.  It appears to be a problem with declaring that the 'output' interface is an aggregation on the mixin interfaces. (see the updated question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to Dynamic Proxy 2.2 or 2.5 It is more permissive and it will let the mixin own the interface and ignore that it was passed again as "additional interface".